# Call a jquery function from a jquery function

Tags: jquery

How can i call a jQuery function from a jQuery function, Both the function are event handler.

My function-

```
$("#myFunction").live("change", function(){
//I want to call my calling function here
});
```

My Calling Function-

```
$("#callingFunction").live("change", function(){

});
```

How can i do this? Need help!

Comment: Name your function and call it...

Comment: It's really weird you name DOM elements "myFunction" and "callingFunction". They are not functions, they are DOM elements. You should give them `id="element1"`, not `id="myFunction"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can make use of [.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)  function available in jquery library to do that.

Example

```
$( "#foo" ).on( "click", function() {
alert( $( this ).text() );
});
$( "#foo" ).trigger( "click" );
```

you can also make use of [change](http://api.jquery.com/change/) function like as below

```
$( ".target" ).change(function() {
alert( "Handler for .change() called." );
});

$( "#other" ).click(function() {
$( ".target" ).change();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function doSomething(){
 /* stuff stuff stuff */
}

$("#element1").on("change", doSomething);
$("#element2").on("change", doSomething);
```

or

```
$("#element1").change(doSomething);
$("#element2").change(doSomething);
```

or even better, as Satpal suggested :

```
$("#element1, #element2").change(doSomething);
```

As of jQuery 1.7, [live() is deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/live/).

And I didn't name my elements "myFunction" and "callingFunction" as they are not functions but DOM elements.

Comment: `$("#myFunction, #callingFunction").on('change', doSomething)`

Answer (score 0):

If you are re-assigning the some behavior after the initial event. I'm not sure if you're looking to chain events, eg

```
$('ele')
.click(function(){})
.hover(function(){})
```

It depends on what you're doing, entirely.